# Adjust barplot x-axis to match metric instead of categorical scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

**Context**

I have a `pandas-DataFrame` containing aggregated data I want to plot as barchart:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x_axis": np.arange(0., 1., .01)
    , "counts": some_aggregation
})

# df looks like this
x_axis |counts 
--------------
0.00   | 1.0    
0.01   | 0.0    
0.02   | 14.0   
...
1.00   | 12.0
```

As can be seen this provides

- `x_axis`: A column I want to use to provide the x-axis since the counts can contain zero-values
- `counts` which is some aggregation coming from a groupby which I want to plot over the provided distribution in `x_axis`.

With `seaborn` or `matplotlib` itself this can easily be visualized:

```
s = sns.barplot(x='x_axis', y="counts", data=df)
```

**Problem**

When I plot the chart as described, the X-ticks get converted to a `range(0, 100)` by `matplotlib` since the provided distribution in `x_axis` is handled as categorical data.
Printing the ticklabels shows this problem:

```py
list(s.get_xticklabels())

# Output
[Text(0, 0, '0.0'),
 Text(1, 0, '0.01'),
 Text(2, 0, '0.02'),
...
]
```

Of course I can set the x-ticklabels to the correct position by executing this:

```py
# Change x-axis-position of x-tick-labels
s.set_xticks(s.get_xticks() * .01)

# Output
[Text(0.0, 0, '0.0'),
 Text(0.01, 0, '0.01'),
 Text(0.02, 0, '0.02'),
...
]
```

Anyhow, while the tick labels themselves are in the correct position now, the chart itself does not update to show the bars above the newly placed labels.

**Question**

Can I do one of the to options:

- Convert the "categorical" scale of `sns.barplot` to a metric one? This would be my favorite solution since I actually want to share the x-axis with other plots whose range is `set_xlim((0., 1.))`.
- Adjust the plot so that the bars match `s.set_xticks(s.get_xticks() * .01)` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `sns.histplot()`, with `weights` and explicitly setting bin boundaries nicely between the x-values:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(0., 1., .01)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x_axis": xs,
                   "counts": np.random.randint(0, 10, len(xs))})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 4))
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x="x_axis", weights="counts", bins=np.arange(-0.005, 1, 0.01))
ax.margins(x=0.005)  # the default margins left and right are too large
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot using weights and explicit bins]

To have more standard x-ticks, `ax.set_xticks(xs)` and the rotation could be left out.

Also note that "np.arange(0., 1., .01)" can be deceptive. As it works with floats, depending on rounding errors, the final `1.0` might be included, or not. One way to deal with this, is to make the end value some epsilon larger (in case you want to include it, e.g. `np.arange(0, 1.0001, .1)`), or smaller (to stop just one value earlier). Or you can create the numbers as integers and then divide (`np.arange(0, 100)/100`).

Comment: Thanks! I adapted the logic to my code and it is working including the sharable x-axis over multpile plots! :)